# how to get and read the data from kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to use the data from kinect,and i have installed the stack openni_kinect;so if i want to get and read the data from kinect,should i need to create a node to publish the relative messages? and how should i create? Or is there another way to complete it? In addition i did not find any information about "publisher" or "service" in the stack openni_kinect.
note：Ubuntu11.10  ROS electric
Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33709/how-to-get-and-read-the-data-from-kinect/) by [Ocean](https://answers.ros.org/users/2058/ocean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're going to want to use the [openni_camera](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera) package and the [openni_launch](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch) package. The `openni_launch` package should have everything you need to get started.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2